# A generalized integral reminiscent of the beta function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to utilize the Beta function somehow with the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\cos^{2k}(x) dx$$

I tried using a phase shift $u=\frac{\pi}{2} - x$, but it came to no avail. I haven’t tried much else since I am out of ideas.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives: $$\pi  4^{-k-1} (2 k)! \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2},k+1;k+\frac{3}{2},k+\frac{3}{2};1\right)$$ where $F$ is a regularized hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2):

We could try to write $\cos ^{2k}x$ in terms of $\cos nx$ where $n$ is an integer.
Consider $z = \cos x + i\sin x \therefore \frac{1}{z} = \cos x -i\sin x$.
$$z + \frac{1}{z} = 2\cos x \implies (z+\frac{1}{z})^{2k} = 2^{2k}\cos ^{2k}x$$
Expanding the left-hand side binomially, we get
$$2^{2k}\cos ^{2k}x = z^{2k}+\frac{1}{z^{2k}}+{2k \choose 1}(z^{2k-2}+\frac{1}{z^{2k-2}})+\cdots+{2k \choose k}$$
Using De Moivre's Formula, $z^{n}+\frac{1}{z^n} = 2cos{nx}$. Applying this to the terms above we get
$$2^{2k}\cos^{2k}x=2\cos({2k})x+{2k \choose 1}2\cos({2k-2})x+\cdots+{2k \choose k}$$
$$\therefore 2^{2k}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos^{2k}xdx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2x\cos({2k})xdx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2x\cos({2k-2})xdx+\cdots+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2k \choose k}xdx$$
Integrals of the form, $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos 2nxdx = \frac{n\pi\sin{n\pi +\cos n\pi-1}}{4n^2}$ where $n = 1,2,\cdots,k$.
I'm not sure if the expression you get can be simplified any further but I hope this gives you some idea.

---

Another approach that came to my mind was deriving a reduction formula. Let
$$I_{2k} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos^{2k} xdx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(x\cos x)\cos^{2k-1} xdx$$
Using Integration by Parts,
$$I_{2k} = \cos ^{2k-1} x (x\sin x + \cos x)|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+(2k-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2k-2}x(x\sin^2x+\sin x \cos x)dx$$
$$I_{2k} = -1+(2k-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos^{2k-2}x\sin^2xdx+(2k-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2k-1}x\sin xdx$$
The last integral is simply $\frac{2k-1}{2k}$
$$I_{2k} = -1+\frac{2k-1}{2k}+(2k-1)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos^{2k-2}x(1-
\cos^2x)dx$$
With a little simplification,
$$I_{2k} = -\frac{1}{2k}+(2k-1)I_{2k-2}-(2k-1)I_n$$
$$\therefore (2k)I_{2k} = -\frac{1}{2k}+(2k-1)I_{2k-2}$$
$$\therefore I_{2k}= -\frac{1}{4k^2} + \frac{2k-1}{2k}I_{2k-2} $$

Comment: I really hope someone can complete the solution from where I left it or even suggest alternative techniques to solve the problem above :)

Comment: This recurrence equation is very nice ! Congratulations and $\to +1$

Comment: Thank you so much! :)